# El print de python no me funciona

Tags: python-2.7

El error lo encontraréis al final del todo

## Calculadora

```
pregunta = raw_input("suma, resta, multiplicacion, division: ")

if pregunta == "suma": 
    valor1 = raw_input("Introduce el numero que quieres sumar ")
    valor2 = raw_input(str(valor1) + " " + "mas"  + ":" + " ")

def suma(valor1, valor2):
    operacion = str(valor1) + str(valor2)
    print ("=" + str(operacion))
```

Una vez abierto el protrama todo va bien y la operación, en teoría, se hace pero después de eso se cierra directamente sin mostrar el resultao ni dar error.

Comment: Modifica tu código para que sea más legible o acepta la edición que tienes pendiente para que sea más facil saber si el error es de sintaxis o de lógica.

Comment: Y donde llamas a la función `suma`???

Answer (score 1):

He hecho un par de cambios los cuales son:

- Llamar a la función de **suma**, la cual tu no haces en tu código (es por ello que no te hace el cálculo).
- Declarar la función **suma** al principio y no al final.
- Tratamiento de excepciones.

A continuación puedes ver el código corregido, espero que te ayude:

```
def sumar(valor1, valor2):
    operacion = int(valor1 + valor2)
    print(str(valor1) +" + "+ str(valor2) + " = " + str(operacion))

try:
    pregunta = str(raw_input("suma, resta, multiplicacion, division: "))
    if(str.lower(pregunta) == "suma"):
        val1 = int(input("Introduce el numero que quieres sumar(1): "))
        val2 = int(input("Introduce el segundo numero que quieres sumar(2): "))
        sumar(val1, val2)
except:
    print("Error")
```

Comment: Muchas grácias, soy nuevo en la programación y he conseguido arreglar mi codigo aunque algunas cosas como try o except no las he entendido.

Comment: Me alegra que los hayas conseguido. El "try" & exept" se usan principal mente para capturar errores como por ejemplo evitar que se introduzca un dato de tipo string en un campo de tipo int.